# How to get a list of domain users on the local machine?

Tags: windows, windows-10, domain

I have a Windows 10 machine that is part of a domain. Currently, a domain user from the domain, `DKNII`, have logged into the machine.

`net user` lists local accounts, whereas `net user /domain` lists all domain accounts. The `DKNII` account only shows up for the latter command.

While offline, I managed to add `DKNII` to local administrators group by `net localgroup administrators DKNII /add`. So, my machine actually knows `DKNII` in offline mode, although `net user /domain` fails.

How do I get a list of domain users, like `DKNII`, that my computer knows in offline mode (the account has logged in previously)?

Comment: You can use PowerShell if you have the required Active Directory modules installed

Comment: What about cmd.exe?

Comment: Easier with PowerShell.

Comment: Can you show how?